# How do I get a thin border in qtip with round corners?

Tags: border, css, qtip

I try to get a thin border with round corners for the tip in qtip, using:

```
border: {width: 1, radius: 7, color: "#B8E25E"}
```

(Like explained here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials#borders)

But the border is then getting quite thick, like 7 or something.  Is there a way to get a thin border with round corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem too - it looks like qtip 1.x will not let you use a 'radius' thats less than the border width.

It looks like this is by design, and you'll have to move to qtip 2 (which isn't released yet) to get round it.

See [this conversation between the developer of qtip and a user](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-border-radius-greater-than-width):

> User: I've played a little with this,
>   and as far as I can detect it isn't
>   possible to use a border-radius that
>   is greater than the border-width. If I
>   configure a border-radius that's
>   greater than the border-width, the
>   border-width displayed will be the
>   same as the radius (in stead of what I
>   configured).
>
> Developer: Unfortunately this is
>   neither a bug or feature, just an side
>   effect of the implementation. There
>   are no plans to implement this as 1.0
>   releases are now discontinued, and the
>   border engine is removed in the 2.0
>   releases in favour of standard
>   border-radius properties.

Answer (score 0):

From briefly glancing at that documentation it looks like the Radius is the width of the border?
So therefore your border is 7, maybe change it to {width: 1, radius: 2, color: "#B8E25E"} to get a thinner border?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code, I found this in the docs.css file:

```
#content .subsection{
      border-bottom: 3px solid #F1F1F1;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      padding: 5px 0 40px;
   }
```

Try doing something similar to this and see what happens.  Maybe saying border: 3px solid #F1F1F1; instead.

Here's the section where I found this at: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials#borders

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you out

.corner {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

Comment: QTip 1 doesn't use CSS for the rounded corners, precisely because Internet explorer <9 has no support. This CSS will have no effect whatsoever else he'd be using QTip 2 which relies on the border-radius css